# Cypress Tests are not parallelly runable on GitHub Actions

Tags: typescript, cypress, github-actions

I am working on the cypress tests execution in parallel but tests are not running in parallel on GitHub Actions, instead, they are running one by one as you can see in the screenshot.

I am using the matrix container here to divide the test tests. and it's divided but tests are running one by one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfeR1.png)

And I have followed the below links:

- https://learn.cypress.io/tutorials/running-our-tests-in-parallel-with-cypress-dashboard
- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/parallelization
- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/github-actions-
- Parallelization | Cypress Documentation

I am using the cypress dashboard/cypress cloud of the free version and GitHub Actions, but after applying the solution mentioned in the above links, the tests are not running in parallel. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is missing the workflow file, or better: the relevant excerpt of it. Please edit it into your question by using the correct formatting, that is a code block. And check your question, the image link is missing a proper title (please do as it states: "enter image description here"). Let us know if you have further questions or need editing help. Compare [mre].

Comment: What command are you using to start your Cypress tests in GHA?